# How to Shutdown Android 4.0 rooted Device programatically

Tags: android, root, android-firmware

Please help me to find out solution for this, I Know there are so many questions and duplicates about this same but here i describe whole things which i tried.

I have one android device where its installed 4.0 version of android.
I want to shutdown this device using my one demo application.

```
1) Demo application is signed by platform keys which are used in built in file system.
2) Device is already rooted as its development board and i have all permissions on this.
```

Application contains Following things

```
1) Application is system application
2) Application signed by platform keys which are used in built in file system.
```

For make automation easier, I did import the `key/cert` pair into my java `keystore` file, with the this [keytool-importkeypair](https://github.com/getfatday/keytool-importkeypair/tree/) and use eclipse for signing.

Used command is mentioned below.

**Commad :** `keytool-importkeypair -k ~/Desktop/myown.keystore -p android -pk8 platform.pk8 -cert platform.x509.pem -alias platform`

I used following code for reboot but i never make success in this .I read So many questions and answers on stackoverflow but they all said you require

```
1) root access of device
2) signed apk with any one keys which are available on `build/target/product/security/`
3) Given Proper permission in AndroidManifest.xml file.
```

Am i right in alomg points?

Application code :

**First Try**

```
public static void shutdown2() {

Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = null;
OutputStreamWriter osw = null;

String command = "/system/bin/reboot -p";

try { // Run Script

    proc = runtime.exec("/system/xbin/su");
    osw = new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream());
    osw.write(command);
    osw.flush();
    osw.close();

} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (osw != null) {
        try {
            osw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
try {
    if (proc != null)
        proc.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if (proc.exitValue() != 0) {
}
 }
```

**Second Try :**

```
private void shutdown3() {
        try {

            String[] cmd = { "/system/bin/sh","su","reboot -p"};

            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.i("TAG", "Could not reboot 3  ", ex);
        }
    }
```

**3rd Try :**

```
private void shutdown() {
        try {
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                    new String[] { "/system/bin/su", "-c",
                            "/system/bin/reboot -p" });
            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.i("TAG", "Could not reboot 1 ", ex);
        }
    }
```

In 3rd method I also tried with `"/system/bin/su"`

Answer (score 1):

The below code worked for me

```
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime()
                .exec(new String[]{ "su", "-c", "busybox poweroff -f"});
        process.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 1):

A much better solution is to run:

`su -c am start -a android.intent.action.ACTION_REQUEST_SHUTDOWN`

You can use a `Process` for this.